# How to merge data from different df using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes and I want to get df, where in first file I have a lot of data and in the second file I have a list of `iD`, that I want get from first file.

I use

```
merged = pd.merge(buys, chunk, left_on='id', right_on='ID')
```

where `chunk` - a part of first(big) file. And `buys` - file with list of `id`. In output file I have `ID`, that not in `buys`. 
What I do wrong?

`buys`:

```
id
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464
bc8a731e4c7e6f6b96e56ebe7f766bcd
a703114aa8a03495c3e042647212fa63
77138e9245857e5449e9474293e31e19
```

`chunk`:

```
id  date
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    01.01.2016
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    02.01.2016
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    03.01.2016
77138e9245857e5449e9474293e31e19    09.05.2016
77138e9245857e5449e9474293e31e19    10.05.2016
671cfd6702c74f017209c2f1a888c279    10.01.2016
671cfd6702c74f017209c2f1a888c279    11.01.2016
029cfd6702c68f243423c2f1a234c232    11.03.2016
```

And I need to get

```
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    01.01.2016
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    02.01.2016
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    03.01.2016
77138e9245857e5449e9474293e31e19    09.05.2016
77138e9245857e5449e9474293e31e19    10.05.2016
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data and the desired output?

Comment: @JoeR, add dataframes

Comment: Add `how=left` to `pd.merge`.

Comment: Is it `id` or `ID`? I can't reproduce it. Could you prepare a small example and paste the output of `print(buys)`, `print(chunk)`, and `pd.merge(buys, chunk, left_on='id', right_on='ID')`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to merge your two dataframes and just keeping the `id` present in `buys`? Then you cann pass the `how` option in your `merge` like this:

```
merged = pd.merge(buys, chunk, left_on='id', right_on='ID', how = 'left')
```

Note that if there are `id` in `buys` that are not in `chunk.ID` you will get `NaN` where the corresponding dates are missing. If you don't want that, change the `how` option to `inner`:

```
merged = pd.merge(buys, chunk, left_on='id', right_on='ID', how = 'inner')
```

This way you will only get the rows that are present in both dataframes.